# python scrapy deny rule

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

i want to create a deny rule (dynamic)... that deny's anything in front of the domain.

Example:

```
https://blog.example.com
https://video.example.com
https://jp.example.com
https://de.exp.com
...
```

And so on.

I tried like this but it doesn't work as expected:

```
domain = 'example.com'

rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=(r"[a-zA-z\.]("+ domain +")")),
                  callback="parse_page",
                  follow=True)]
```

basicaly deny anything thats in front of domain...except **https://**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I think it should work as follow:

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(deny='.*' + domain + '.*',
                  callback="parse_page",
                  follow=True)]
```

For dynamic links you can use `tldextract` on the response.url inside `parse` function. For example:

```
import tldextract

deny_regex = '.*' + tldextract.extract(url).domain + '.*'
```